# Extending react component Composition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am looking at extending a component in React. I have [read this in the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) that it is recommended to use composition instead of inheritance to reuse code between components.

Based on this I implemented the following and believed that this is the correct approach. (It does work). See code below.

```
class ComponentExtension extends Component {

  //*** extras to extend the original component here  ***//
  //*** omitted for the purposes of this question ***//

  render() {
    return <OriginalComponent />;
  }

}
```

However, then upon further research I came across [Higher Order Components in the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html). What is the difference between the two approaches? Should you use one approach in one instance and another approach in a separate instance? Are they even solving an identical problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend the component, you should do something like this:

```
class ComponentExtension extends OriginalComponent {
      //***  extras ***//
}
```

And if you use HOC, you just wrap one component into the other.

Comment: I originally did that but if you read here it is recommended not to do that https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html. You should choose composition over inheritance